# Как вызвать include на perl?

Tags: include, perl

Народ, подскажите кому не трудно как вызвать include на perl?  
гуглил, находил пару обсуждений, там был написан пример что типа вот так

```
require "./core/functions/functions_perl_server.pl";
```

но таким образом у меня выдаёт ошибку

> Внутренняя ошибка сервера

возможно это из за того что у меня перл в cgi формате ? если да то как мне подключить скрипт

пробовал отдельно для интереса вот так вот

**test.cgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
# !usr/local/bin/perl

require "test_mess.pl";

print "test message: ".$test_text;
```

**test_mess.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
# !usr/local/bin/perl

$test_text = "hashcode.ru";
```

---

на коменты ниже ответ на 
(из за чего то я не могу больше комментировать больше на ответ ниже возможно ограничение какое то напишу сюда из за этого)

**$ cat ./1.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $var2 = 'var1';
require '2.pl';
print2();
print "$var2\n";
$var2 = 'var3';
print2();
print "$var2\n";
```

**$ cat ./2.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $var2 = 'var2';
sub print2 { print "$var2\n"; }
```

будет такой, выводит var2 var1 var2 var3
только я чутка под редактировал скрипт но не значительно

**1.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
# !usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;

print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
my$var2 = "var1";
require "2.pl";
print2();
print "$var2\n";
$var2 = "var3";
print2();
print "$var2\n";
```

**2.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
# !usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;

my$var2 = "var2";
sub print2 { print "$var2\n"; }
```

иначе не получалось запустить скрипты

Comment: Одинарные ковычки не пробовали?

Comment: да пробовал также пробовал и require ("наш файл");

Comment: может ему нужен полный путь. я просто уже давненько не вникал в perl

Comment: тоже пробовал (

Comment: другие скрипты работают замечательно где нету require, может быть что у меня какая то старая версия perl стоит ? где нету require, права на файлы пробовал даже уже ставить 777 всё равно не работает

Comment: `require './lib/connect.pl';
require './lib/lib.pm' || die;
require './models/models.pl';` Чет у меня все инклюдится

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, в CGI первыми строчками должны быть (после `use strict`, само собой):

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

Тогда и понятней станет что именно за ошибка.

Во-вторых, подозрительные места можно отлавливать и так:

```
eval { require "test_mess.pl"; };
die "Ошибка при require: $@\n" if $@;
```

В-третьих, подобный require - это пример того, как делать не надо никогда. Даже для пробы и/или ради интереса.

В-четвёртых, если это CGI, то где вывод HTTP-заголовков? Впрочем, дальше уже гадания пошли, пункты 1 и 2 должны хоть что-то прояснить.

А по поводу кода из комментария ниже могу предложить помедитировать над этим:

`$ cat ./1.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $var2 = 'var1';
require '2.pl';
print2();
print "$var2\n";
$var2 = 'var3';
print2();
print "$var2\n";
```

`$ cat ./2.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $var2 = 'var2';
sub print2 { print "$var2\n"; }
```

При запуске 1.pl должно выводиться 4 строки. Но какие именно?

Comment: спасибо думаю дальше уже разберусь ото было не понятно где именно ошибка щя почитаю мож что исправлю просто там вышла куча ошибок )

Comment: (В-третьих, подобный require - это пример того, как делать не надо никогда. Даже для пробы и/или ради интереса.)
а как же ? делать весь код в одном скрипте ? я думаю это не оч удобно когда код очень большой, или есть другой способ ?

Comment: (В-четвёртых, если это CGI, то где вывод HTTP-заголовков?)
в примере что я привёл их нету да а вот уже в скрипте что нужно мне там есть

Comment: в тестовом скрипте я решил проблему с подключением скрипта просто нужно было до подключение его объявить переменные в которые уже потом помещаем нащи значение, но меня интерисует вопрос зачем этот метод не надо не когда применять ?

Comment: Из того, что require можно использовать на манер PHP-шного include, не следует, что так делать - правильно и полезно :) Наборот, это очень "bad practice". Если в проекте много файлов - есть механизм модулей, и вот в его рамках допустимо использовать `require ModuleName` (но не `require файл`). Только смысла нет, так как возможности `use ...` в сочетании с другими вещами (EXPORT, etc) куда больше.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

require/include с исполняемым кодом не очень хорошая идея, лучше сделать модуль и вызывать функции.

Для чтения же конфига бывает удобно применять do

Файл myvars.pm:

```
var1 => 'string',
var2 => 5,
```

Файл с кодом:

```
my %conf = do 'myvars.pm';
print "$conf{var1} = $conf{var2}\n";
```

Вывод будет:

```
string = 5
```